# Cube.dev - how to have the parameter "today date" in rolling window?

Tags: postgresql, cube.js

I have a PostgreSQL database in which *users can order from a start date to an end date*.
I want to know, for each day, how many users would be able to order.

Let's make an example, given:

| id | from | to |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2023-01-01 | 2023-01-03 |
| B | 2023-01-02 | 2023-01-07 |
| C | 2023-01-02 | 2023-01-09 |
| D | 2023-01-10 | 2023-01-12 |

For the first two weeks (let's suppose that the 01/01/2023 were on Monday), I would have (the third column is not needed):

| day | n_of_users_that_can_order | who |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | 1 | A |
| 2023-01-02 | 3 | A, B, C |
| 2023-01-03 | 3 | A, B, C |
| 2023-01-04 | 2 | B, C |
| 2023-01-05 | 2 | B, C |
| 2023-01-06 | 2 | B, C |
| 2023-01-07 | 2 | B, C |
| 2023-01-08 | 1 | C |
| 2023-01-09 | 1 | C |
| 2023-01-10 | 1 | D |
| 2023-01-11 | 1 | D |
| 2023-01-12 | 0 |  |
| 2023-01-13 | 0 |  |
| 2023-01-14 | 0 |  |

My end result should be the above table aggregated per week:

| week | total |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 to 2023-01-07 | 15 |
| 2023-01-08 to 2023-01-14 | 4 |

I don't know how to do it with cube.dev, this is the idea I had for now:

```js
ube(`Users`, {
  sql: `SELECT * FROM public.users`,

  measures: {
    usersPerDayThatCanOrder: {
      type: `count`,
      sql: `id`,
      rollingWindow: {
        trailing: `1 day`,
        offset: `start`
      },
      filters: [
        { sql: `${CUBE}.can_order_from >= ${TODAY} AND ${CUBE}.can_order_to <= ${TODAY}` }, // NOTE: today doesn't exist
      ]
    }
  },

  dimensions: {
    id: {
      sql: `id`,
      type: `number`,
      primaryKey: true
    },

    canOrderFrom: {
      sql: `can_order_from`,
      type: `time`
    },

    canOrderTo: {
      sql: `can_order_to`,
      type: `time`
    },
  },

  dataSource: `default`
});
```

But it does not work because I do not know how to have the real ${TODAY} value and also how to aggregate per week.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sql query which provides your expected result assuming that your table is named `test` :

```
SELECT d.week AS "week start"
     , (d.week + interval '6 days') :: date AS "week end"
     , sum( upper(daterange(d.week, (d.week + interval '1 week') :: date, '[)') * daterange(t."from", t."to", '[]'))
          - lower(daterange(d.week, (d.week + interval '1 week') :: date, '[)') * daterange(t."from", t."to", '[]'))
          )
  FROM
     ( SELECT generate_series(min(date_trunc('week', "from")), max("to"), interval '1 week') :: date AS week
         FROM test
     ) AS d
 INNER JOIN test AS t
    ON daterange(d.week, (d.week + interval '1 week') :: date, '[)') && daterange(t."from", t."to", '[]')
 GROUP BY d.week
 ORDER BY d.week
```

- The subquery calculates the weeks start date covered by table `test`
- The `INNER JOIN` clause intersects the weeks with the user date ranges
- Then rows are concatenated by weeks and the number of days are summed for all the users

By the way, the 2023/01/01 seems not to be Monday but Sunday.

Result :

| week start | week end | sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-12-26 | 2023-01-01 | 1 |
| 2023-01-02 | 2023-01-08 | 15 |
| 2023-01-09 | 2023-01-15 | 4 |

see test result in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Szv8s9P3)

Comment: What about cube.dev?

Comment: no idea, sorry, I let you adapt the sql query in cube.dev